# Post request on click of a button android studio

Tags: java, android

I am creating an app for Phillips Hue Lights and I want to be able to click a button, which will do the post request from my app to a specific URL of the Hue Bridge to get a username returned.

My Code:

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;

public class Device extends AppCompatActivity {

HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_device);
    {

        params.put("devicetype", "final_year_project#michelle");

        PostHandler handler = new PostHandler(params);
        try {
            JSONObject response = handler.execute("http://192.168.1.85/api/").get();

            Log.d("TEST_RESPONSE", response.toString());

        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
}
```

I have also created my PostHandler class:

```
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import okhttp3.FormBody;
import okhttp3.OkHttpClient;
import okhttp3.Request;
import okhttp3.RequestBody;
import okhttp3.Response;

public class PostHandler extends AsyncTask<String, Void, JSONObject> {

OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();

public PostHandler(HashMap params) {
    this.params = params;
}

public PostHandler() {

}

@Override
protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... url) {

    client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .connectTimeout(5, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
            .writeTimeout(5, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
            .readTimeout(5, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
            .build();

    FormBody.Builder body = new FormBody.Builder();

    for ( Map.Entry<String, String> entry : params.entrySet() ) {
        body.add( entry.getKey(), entry.getValue() );
    }

    RequestBody formBody = body.build();

    Request request = new Request.Builder()
            .url(url[0])
            .post(formBody)
            .build();

    try{
        Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
        String result = response.body().string();
        JSONObject json = new JSONObject(result);
        return json;
    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return null;
}
```

}

I am getting an error "cannot resolve symbol params" and the post request does not work.

Does anyone know where I am going wrong? I am new to working with API's.

Comment: Where is the declaration of the variable `params` in your code?

Comment: You did never declare or initialize params and you should also show your PostHandler class.

Comment: Can you pls share complete code of class with this information its not clear why is that error occurring.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following line after `setContentView(R.layout.activity_device);`:

```
ContentValues params = new ContentValues();
```

You have not declared the variable `params` anywhere in your code.

Comment: I have updated my question with the PostHandler class I had created and have declared my variable params. The app just crashes and does not do a Post Request to the URL (Hue Bridge)

Comment: Post that crash log.